# formatting a string to a currency format in jasper report

Tags: java, string, formatting, jasper-reports

I have a string with some numeric value.

I want to format it in a way where hundreds are comma separated and the number is having $ dollar sign before it.

e.g. 12345 should be formatted to $ 12,345.00

I tried the below code without dollar sign:

```
new java.text.DecimalFormat(#,##0.00).format.(myString)
```

and the below one with dollar sign:

```
new java.text.DecimalFormat($ #,##0.00).format.(myString)
```

However, both are giving error.

What is the right way to achieve this format ?

This is a part of jasper report jrxml where I want to avoid "null" on the report and thus inserting the below code:

```
<textField isBlankWhenNull="false" isStretchWithOverflow="true">            
  <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="1350" y="0" width="150" height="30"/>             
      <textElement/>             
   <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$F{myString}!=null?new java.text.DecimalFormat(#,##0.00).format.($F{myString}):"Unavailable"]]></textFieldExpression>        
</textField>
```

Where myString results from a query and is declared in jrxml as:

```
 <field name="myString" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

Earlier myString was declared as BigDecimal, but then comparison operator ?= was not working.

If the currency value is not available, I want to print "unavailable" on the report instead of default "null". Else, I want the number to be properly formatted as described above.

How to resolve this issue?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The correct expression is:

```
new java.text.DecimalFormat("$ #,##0.00").format(Double.valueOf($P{strParam}))
```

The working sample for ***java.lang.Integer*** and ***java.lang.String***:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="format_as_current" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <parameter name="intParam" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[12345678]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="strParam" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["12345678.95"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="137" y="18" width="291" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.DecimalFormat("$ #,##0.00").format($P{intParam})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="137" y="48" width="291" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.DecimalFormat("$ #,##0.00").format(Double.valueOf($P{strParam} != null && $P{strParam}.length() > 0 ? Double.valueOf($P{strParam}) : 0))]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The result will be (preview in *iReport*):

[image: The result in *iReport*]

***Note:***
You should also add check for null.

You can also use ***pattern*** property of *textField* for formatting data.

The sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="format_as_current" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <parameter name="intParam" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[12345678]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="strParam" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["12345678.95"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="148" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField pattern="$ #,##0.00">
                <reportElement x="218" y="99" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{intParam}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="$ #,##0.00">
                <reportElement x="218" y="119" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{strParam} != null && $P{strParam}.length() > 0 ? Double.valueOf($P{strParam}) : 0]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The result will be the same.

Comment: Thanks Alex, will try it out!

Comment: Double.valueOf is giving error "<identifier> expected"... I found this - "u need to specify the compile class path if ur using libraries external to jasper reports" --- but could not find out how to achieve it!

Comment: What tool are you using for testing report (iReport or something else)? Did you set language for report as *Java*?

Comment: Alex  you should suggest the use of pattern to have correct result in xls export (as number), invert methods??

Comment: Why the currency values does not apply from current locale in Jasper?

Comment: can i ask something,@AlexK regarding this matter? How about if we use another country currency? For example in Indonesia, it use "Rp." Instead of "$" and also the decimal point is using comma instead of dot.

Answer (score 4):

Just came accross this Problem and found a solution which is working fine for me.

Be Aware - its not exactly what the Autor is asking for but if you google this Problem you will end up here.

I have Servers with German and English Locale and on all the Currency should be like `7.500,60`

My final expression:

```
new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0.00", new java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols(java.util.Locale.GERMANY)).format($F{variable}) + " €"
```

so the Locale Setting is "hardcoded" - exactly what i needed.

Maybe this will help someone

Comment: if the country locale definition is not given over there? How to make it anyway? For example, Indonesia is not listed inside java.util.Locale. @Frankstar

Comment: @gumuruh you can use new java.util.Locale, ex: for Brazil, I use `new java.util.Locale("pt", "BR")`

Answer (score 4):

Using `DecimalFormat` is not optimal. For formatting currencies, we should use `NumberFormat`. With `NumberFormat` we are way more flexible; we can set dynamically the current locale and the currencies are automatically adapted to the selected locale.

```xml
<![CDATA[ NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance($P{REPORT_LOCALE}).format($F{price}) ]]>
```

We can set the locale with the `REPORT_LOCALE` parameter

```
def params = [REPORT_LOCALE: new Locale("sk", "SK")]
def jrPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jrReport, params, ds)
```

or with the `net.sf.jasperreports.default.locale` property.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.default.locale=sk_SK
```

see https://zetcode.com/jasperreports/formatcurrency/ for a working example.

Comment: this is the correct answer guys

Answer (score 3):

The above code can work for three cases:

1. fix two zeros after decimal point. When I tried to use "Double" datatype for this  purpose it did not work for me. But this code can do it.
2. Fix $ -sign before the number in string datatype and also takes care of "-" sign in its own.
3. Get "," after 3 digits in a number

For me i wanted to put "," comma after every three digits (by passing string as a parameter) and i tried the following code. It did work for me.... Thank you very much. I appreciate this answer.

```
<textFieldExpression>

<![CDATA[new java.text.DecimalFormat("$ #,##0.00").format(Double.valueOf($P{actualWrittenPremium} != null && $P{actualWrittenPremium}.length() > 0 ? Double.valueOf($P{actualWrittenPremium}) : 0))]]>

</textFieldExpression>
```

Answer (score 1):

Im using iReport 5.6.0 and I took some of these answers but what It worked for me was:

Text Field (I put this into the designer):

```
Float.valueOf($V{DISPONIBLE_FINAL})
```

And in the Pattern (into properties tab), I used Custom Format with:

```
$#,##0.00
```

Putting all the string mentioned here in a whole "Edit expression" field didnt worked for me.

Hope It helps.

PD: I was using groovy jar that is the compatible with jasper 5.6.0 checked in mvnrepository site.

Answer (score 1):

When trying the recommended answer in iReport, I got "illegal string body character after dollar sign;" when I ran the report.

Easily remedied by escaping the dollar sign with a backslash like so:

```
new java.text.DecimalFormat("\$ #,##0.00").format(Double.valueOf($F{le1_feeAmount}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this also using the iReport Studio.
In the studio click on the field and see the properties pane.In properties pane under **Text Field Properties** you'll find the **Pattern** property. Paste **#,##0.00** or click on the three dots and tick the check box in the popup menu to separate at 1000.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the locale, this works for me:

```java
     new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0.00", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH)).format(Double.valueOf($F{7}))
```

Comment: Use text formatting options available in StackOverflow editor to improve the readability of your answer.