# Format String to Number iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

i want to generate raport in ireport with existing database.
I have fields in strings `$F{Price}` and varible `$V{SumPrice}` in strings too, and need to convert to integer and sum whole column with field `Price`

Can in do it in ireport ?
I dont have access to the database.

Comment: I forgot:string value(for example - 250) as String and I want to sum it to integer  print on textfield, How to do this

Comment: possible duplicate of [formatting a string to a currency format in jasper report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913495/formatting-a-string-to-a-currency-format-in-jasper-report). You can use variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set $V{SumPrice} "Variable class" property to `java.lang.Integer` and "Variable Expression" property to `Integer.parseInt($F{Price})`.