# Format number in JasperReports: how to trim zeroes

Tags: java, jasper-reports, number-formatting

I got trouble with format number in JasperReports.
For example, i have a double value, and i put the format pattern like `#,##0.000`

Now, with value of number 1.123, i got what i want, but if the value is only 1, or 1.2 it return 1.000 and 1.200, not 1.2 or 1. How can i trim all unnecessary zero in this case.

Here is piece of *jrxml*:

```
<textField pattern="#,##0.000;-#,##0.000" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement x="2390" y="0" width="60" height="25"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{C9} == null ? 0 : $F{C9}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [formatting a string to a currency format in jasper report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913495/formatting-a-string-to-a-currency-format-in-jasper-report) & [How to nicely format floating numbers to String without unnecessary decimal 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/703396/876298)

Answer (score 2):

That pattern is a standard Java pattern used to format decimal numbers. You can find more info in the [Javadoc for DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). The JasperReports engine internally feeds that pattern to a `java.text.DecimalFormat` instance.

In your case a more generic pattern like `#,###.###` should do it. There is no need for the negative pattern as it is optional and inferred from the positive one.

Simple *Java* code

```
NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#,###.###");
System.out.println(format.format(1.200));
System.out.println(format.format(1.210));
System.out.println(format.format(1.213));
System.out.println(format.format(1.2137));
```

gives us results:

```
1,2
1,21
1,213
1,214
```