# Jasper report XLS export shows value as String instead of Currency

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have a similar issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913495/formatting-a-string-to-a-currency-format-in-jasper-report) but with the value type instead of value pattern. I have a value called 'Balance'

```
<parameter name="Balance" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

and corresponding field

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement x="400" y="55" width="117" height="7"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Top">
        <font size="7" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[( $P{Balance}.equals(null) ? "" : $P{Balance} )]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

When I export my Jasper report as XLS, 'Balance' value comes in correct pattern (ie. $400.20) but Excel consider this as a String instead of Currency.

Any idea how to fix it would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you are using a String to display a Number and wondering why Excel considers this as a String? Using Double or Float seems to be more efficient.

Comment: No, I am not surprise but when I've tried to simply change parameter to different type it was breaking my template. So still not sure what is the exact fix for it.

Comment: I could help you more, if you would add the jrxml file (remove personal data before).